# compilation error of .pc file "PCC-S-02015, unable to open include file" and "PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "size_t" "

Tags: c, compiler-errors, proc

I made a .pc code for DB connectivity. But it fails due to compilation error. I am running below command:

```
proc connectivity.c
```

And getting output as :

```
/Pro*C/C++: Release 12.1.0.1.0 - Production on Wed Jul 17 18:54:54 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

System default option values taken from: 
/u01/app2/ora12c/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg

Error at line 33, column 11 in file /usr/include/stdio.h
# include <stddef.h>
..........1
PCC-S-02015, unable to open include file
Error at line 15, column 10 in file /usr/include/_G_config.h
#include <stddef.h>
.........1
PCC-S-02015, unable to open include file
Error at line 51, column 11 in file /usr/include/wchar.h
# include <stddef.h>
..........1
PCC-S-02015, unable to open include file
Error at line 50, column 10 in file /usr/include/libio.h
#include <stdarg.h>
.........1
PCC-S-02015, unable to open include file
Syntax error at line 307, column 3, file /usr/include/libio.h:
Error at line 307, column 3 in file /usr/include/libio.h
  size_t __pad5;
..1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "size_t" when expecting one of the 
following
:

   } char, const, double, enum, float, int, long, ulong_varchar,
   OCIBFileLocator OCIBlobLocator, OCIClobLocator, OCIDateTime,
   OCIExtProcContext, OCIInterval, OCIRowid, OCIDate, OCINumber,
   OCIRaw, OCIString, short, signed, sql_context, sql_cursor,
   struct, union, unsigned, utext, uvarchar, varchar, void,
   volatile, a typedef name,
The symbol "enum," was substituted for "size_t" to continue.
```

I checked all header files are present. This issue is coming from some library variables and functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the sys_include variable in "**/u01/app2/ora12c/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg**" file. Some of the include paths were not available. Those directories were not found in the server. I tried to include the path during compilation ( Alternate way is to change path in pcscfg.cfg ).

```
proc  include=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/include connection.pc
```

And the issue was resolved.